# Rendering data on link click on a different tab

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this `Test` as react component which is having a link `book`.When I click this link I want to open a new tab with url `/book-data` and render `Book` component.Also I have to pass `book_id` from `Test` to `Book` as `Book` is showing this data.

```
class Test extends React.Component {

  render() {
  const book_id = 123;
    return (
      <div>
        <a href="/book-data">book</a>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Test;
```

`Book` component showing book_id

```
import React from "react";
class Book extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.book_id}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Book;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your Route something like this:

`<Route path="book-data/:id" component={Book} />`

Then from `Test` Component render `Book` Component

`render() {
  const book_id = 123;
    return (
      <div>
        <a href="/book-data/{book_id}">book</a>
      </div>
    )
  }`

Now in `Book` Component you can get `book_id` like this:

`componentDidMount(){
        var book_id = this.props.params.id;
    }`